# Is Nested Describes Acceptable For The Purpose Of Readability?

Tags: automated-testing, e2e

Is it ok to have a nested describe for the purpose of read ability? Example:

```
describe('Atlas Search ', () => {
    beforeEach(() => browser.pause(20));

    before(()=> {
      searchPage.home();
      searchPage.searchBtn.click();
    });

    describe('When searching for items', () => {
      before(() => searchPage.searchBox.setValue('Darth'));

      it('should give 2 drop down hints', () => {
        browser.pause(800);

        [
          'Star Wars - Darth Vader',
          'Star Wars - Darth Maul',
        ].forEach((assertion, i) => {
          const el = searchPage.searchHints[i+1];
          const elText = searchPage.getHintText(el);
          elText.should.equal(assertion);
        });
      });

    });
})
```

```
[chrome  linux #0-0] Atlas Search
[chrome  linux #0-0]     When searching for items
[chrome  linux #0-0]        ✓ should give 2 drop down hints
[chrome  linux #0-0]
[chrome  linux #0-0] 1 passing (5.2s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of describe is to allow BDD format:

```
describe('Given user logins', () => {
    describe('Given user Selects payment', () => {
        describe('Given user clicks pay', () => {
            it('Then deducts payment', () => {   

            })    
        })
    })
})
```

So it's perfectly fine to nest the describe. You can write steps in each describe block using **beforeEach**

```
describe('Given user logins', () => {

    beforeEach(async function() {
         login();
    });

    describe('Given user Selects payment', () => {

        beforeEach(async function() {
            selectpayment();
        });

        describe('Given user clicks pay', () => {
            it('Then deducts payment', () => {  

            })    
        })
    })
})
```